# Quotient group of the intersection of normal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G$ be a group, $H,K$ be its normal subgroups, let $I = H \cap K$. Obviously $I$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

Show that $(HK/I) \cong (H/I) \times (K/I)$

I have defined a map 
$$\alpha: (H/I) \times (K/I) \longrightarrow (HK/I)$$
$$\alpha(I_h,I_k) = I_{hk}$$

I have shown that this map is a well defined homomorphism. But how do I show that the inverse is also a homomorphism?

Comment: I would instead show that it's injective and surjective. (Your original way is possible, but it's less breakable-into-parts.) Can you do either of those?

Comment: I think surjective is obvious, but injective would be a bit tricky

Comment: How did you prove well-defined, out of interest? "Injective" is just the converse to "well-defined", so have you checked whether your proof of well-definedness reverses?

Comment: I have shown that if

$h_1 (h_2)^{-1} \in I$, $k_1 (k_2)^{-1} \in I$ then
$h_1 k_1 (k_2)^{-1} (h_2)^{-1} \in I$

But the converse I'm not quite sure